# Make password visible in Windows 8 App (C# & XAML) PasswordBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

by default, the password stored in a `PasswordBox` is hidden behind a masking character. This can be changed from the default, a caret, to another character using `PasswordBox.PasswordChar`.

My question is this: Is there a way to remove the masking function altogether, in other words make the password visible?

Obviously your first thought might be to use a plain text entry field, however, the user has the ability to show or hide repeatedly, at will. While using this solution I could replace the password with carets and store the real password in a variable, and then replace it with the real password again if the user wants it visible, I don't like the idea because it makes for a lot of somewhat messy code.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain your problem clearly? You can do whatever you want with text entry field.

Comment: My question specifically is whether or not there is a way to make the contents of a `PasswordBox`. All the rest is just background information. I _could_ use a text entry, but would prefer not to due the the shuffling required.

Comment: @Razick - you think that moving a text string into/outOf a text box is messy?

Comment: @MartinJames Not particularly. It's just that for such a simple function I hoped to avoid a bunch of if/elses etc. It's not a big deal, I just hoped for a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that, for security reasons, the `PasswordBox` control does not allow this.  Another way to do it would be to have the `PasswordBox` control and a hidden plain text box.  When the user chooses to show the password you copy the string to the text box and show that and hide the PasswordBox.  Obscuring the password again is just the opposite process.